# Lock a column while scrolling with QTableWidget / QTableView?

Tags: qtableview, qtablewidget, qt4.7

Is it possible to hold the position of one column , while i'm scrolling horizontally in QTableWidget / QTableView ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at following example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html

Comment: Broken link, not helpful anymore.