# How to freeze a column of a QTableWidget, not a QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget

I'd like to freeze a chosen column so it keeps beeing seen when scrolling horizontally using a QTableWidget. Similar to what MSAccess or Excel do. You can see an example of a solution here (but using a QTableView):

- C++: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html
- Python: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html

I know there are duplicated posts about this question:

- [Lock a column while scrolling with QTableWidget / QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427963/lock-a-column-while-scrolling-with-qtablewidget-qtableview)
- [How to freeze particular row / column in QTableWidget python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975780/how-to-freeze-particular-row-column-in-qtablewidget-python)

But none of them actually give a solution without having to use a QTableView, and they always refer to the qt documentation mentioned above.

The problem is that QTableView is very limited, the signals provided by this widget are worse than what QTableWidget has in the other hand...
So i'm asking again this question to see if anyone has a solution for this.

I've also tryied to implement two separated QTableWidgets, linking their scrollingbars, but its not precise, and the bars end up unsyncronized. Example: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-November/030646.html

I'd actually like something like this:
https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/itemviews/frozencolumn
but using a QTableWidget instead.

Hope anyone can help, please don't duplicate this question because it hasn't been answered properly in any of the questions like this one.
Also, I'm programming with python but C++ code would help anyways, I'd do my best to translate it.

Thanks you all

Comment: `QTableWidget` is a subclass of `QTableView`.The only significant difference is that the former is item-based, whilst the latter is index-based.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I think I'm not understanding the use that I should do to QTableView then... Can I have repeat what they do with QTableView using a QTableWidget?

Comment: Why not just try ii and see what happens?